# How to handle callbacks for dependencies of children/custom hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Wondering what the best method is to handle callbacks that get passed to children/into custom hooks that are used inside useEffect blocks (or any hook with dependency arrays)

This is going by the assumption we don't have access to that callback to wrap in a useCallback or define it outside of the parent/changing scope ourselves.

Is there better ways than suggested below? Do I need to worry about stale fns/closures?

```js
function Parent() {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
    const onChange = (value) => {
        setValue(value);
    }

    return (
        <Child onChange={onChange} />
    )
}

function Child({ onChange }) {
    useEffect(() => {
        // ...
        onChange(changingValue);
    }, [changingValue, onChange]); // <- always changing 
}

// Is there a drawback to this approach? 
function Child({ onChange }) {
    const callbackRef = useRef();
    callbackRef.current = onChange;

    useEffect(() => {
        // ...
        callbackRef.current(changingValue);
    }, [changingValue]) 
}

// or should it be updated in useLayoutEffect?
function Child({ onChange }) {
    const callbackRef = useRef();

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        callbackRef.current = onChange;
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        // ...
        callbackRef.current(changingValue);
    }, [changingValue]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best is the first one, it's simpler, and if you use a useCallback where you define onChange, then the function will be called just one time every time the value changes, like this:

```
function Parent() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);

  const onChange = useCallback((input) => {
      setValue(input);
  }, []);

  return (
      <Child onChange={onChange} />
  )
}

function Child({ onChange }) {
  const [changingValue, setChangingValue] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
      onChange(changingValue);
  }, [changingValue, onChange]);  

  return (
    <input type="text" value={changingValue} onChange={(event) => setChangingValue(event.target.value)} />
  )
}
```

By the way, in this particular case, of course you can call the function directly on the onChange, passing the value, like this:

```
function Parent() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);

  const onChange = useCallback((input) => {
      setValue(input);
  }, []);

  return (
      <Child onChange={onChange} value={value} />
  )
}

function Child({ onChange, value }) {
  return (
    <input type="text" value={value} onChange={(event) => onChange(event.target.value)} />
  )
}
```

Comment: Yeah I get that, this is referring to when you don't have access to the function passed through however (not being able to wrap the parent fn)